# Modal form doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, header

I found nice modal form at http://www.bootply.com/60244, but when I try run it in my code I get empty content after click on "Launch Modal". Probably I don't have some stylesheet or library.

```
<head>
<title></title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic&subset=latin,latin-ext" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Anyone know what I need to run it? On bootply everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap makes use of certain HTML elements and CSS properties that [require the use of the HTML5 doctype](http://getbootstrap.com/css/). Include it at the beginning of all your projects.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
...
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason - Bootstrap v2.3.1, I using 3.3+.